# Use a Column instance w/ functions.expr in PySpark

Tags: pyspark

In my PySpark app, I have a variable named `my_col` which is an instance of Spark `Column`. It is returned by a complex function and I don't have control over how that is produced. Now I would like to use it with `functions.expr("SOME_FUNC(my_col)")`. Obviously, I cannot directly pass this `Column` and use it as a string which is required by `functions.expr`. Is there anyway I can make this work? Thanks.